# Download a PDF using PhoneGap to be viewed offline?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, pdf, download

I'm developing an iPhone app where the user can download files (.pdf, .docx etc) using PhoneGap and HTML in Xcode and then either view them 'Online' (*where essentially the user views the files from the website they were downloaded from*) or 'Offline' (*where the user has pre-downloaded them, right now it's being hardcoded what files are being downloaded, and can view the file from the LocalFileSystem on the device*). I can download a .txt file fine;

```
    function downloadEditFile() {
        var fileDownloadEdit = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97184921/editme.txt");

        fileDownloadEdit.download(
                uri,
                pathToRoot + '/editme.txt',
                function(entry) {
                    console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                    alert("File Downloaded. Click 'Read Editable Downloaded File' to see text");
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                    console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
                }
        );
    }
```

but when i try and develop it to download a .pdf file it breaks. i need help, where am i going wrong? all i really do is change the file name to `Holidays.pdf`, but the `console` comes up saying;

```
2013-03-14 11:06:47.921 TestApp1[265:15b03] -[CDVFileTransfer download:] [Line 313] File Transfer downloading file...
2013-03-14 11:06:48.553 TestApp1[265:15b03] File Transfer Finished with response code 404
2013-03-14 11:06:48.553 TestApp1[265:15b03] -[CDVFileTransferDelegate connectionDidFinishLoading:] [Line 437] Write file /Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/AF96D141-0CE5-4D60-9FA8-8A8F9A999C81/Documents/Holidays.pdf
2013-03-14 11:06:48.554 TestApp1[265:15b03] FileTransferError {
code = 3;
"http_status" = 404;
source = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97184921/Internship%2520Stuff/Holidays.pdf";
target = "/Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/AF96D141-0CE5-4D60-9FA8-8A8F9A999C81/Documents/Holidays.pdf";
}
2013-03-14 11:06:48.556 TestApp1[265:15b03] [LOG] download error source http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97184921/Internship%2520Stuff/Holidays.pdf
2013-03-14 11:06:48.556 TestApp1[265:15b03] [LOG] download error target /Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/AF96D141-0CE5-4D60-9FA8-8A8F9A999C81/Documents/Holidays.pdf
2013-03-14 11:06:48.557 TestApp1[265:15b03] [LOG] upload error code3
```

whats going wrong? i'm fairly new to Xcode and PhoneGap so any help at all would be great :)

Here's the exact JavaScript for downloading a pdf file;

```
    function downloadPDFFile() {
        var fileDownloadPDF = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97184921/Internship%20Stuff/Holidays.pdf");

        fileDownloadPDF.download(
                                  uri,
                                  pathToRoot + '/Holidays.pdf',
                                  function(entry) {
                                  console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                                  alert("File Downloaded. Click 'Read Editable Downloaded File' to see text");
                                  },
                                  function(error) {
                                  console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                                  console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                                  console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
                                  }
                                  );
    }
```

and the HTML I use to call the function is;

```
<button onclick="downloadPDFFile();">Download PDF File</button> <br>
```

Comment: I am getting an error that FileTransfer is not defined. Is there a third party library that you are using for that or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your URL is wrong. I think the JS is literally translating the % in your URI string. (line 3 of the JS)

If you look at the URL in the console output it's "Internship%2520..." Not "Internship%20".
Pretty sure that's why you're getting a 404 on the file which obviously means it can't be downloaded.

Rename your DB folder to not have a space in it... use an underscore or just make it all one word.